Borrowing money from friend abroad
I live in Belgium and want to buy an apartment. I don’t have enough money to get a loan from the bank. I have a friend which lives outside of Europe and he can lend me money equal to full cost of the apartment with zero % of interest and I am free to give the money back whenever I want.
My question is it allowed, will I pay any kind of taxes?

Have you ever met that friend in real life? Do they have other friends who tend to fall out of windows or go to swim face-down in concrete? If the whole thing is legit and kosher and you really have such a wondrous benefactor then I'd like to be their friend too.

Please review the many questions tagged "scam". This sounds like the classic setup for somebody promising to eventually send you money, but in actuality getting you to send them lots of money "to cover the fees". Or sending you a fake check and asking you to send them a real one. Or any of several other criminal patterns.Unless this is a close family member, run away. And frankly, I would be skeptical of those terms from anyone except my parents and my brother.

Thanks a lot for your comments. This is very trusted person. My main question at this moment how Belgium authorities will look at that in terms of taxes.

The reason we make these types of comments is because 98% of the people who come on here and ask about things that turn out to be scams would also swear blind that "This is very trusted person."

Also, did you google? https://www.vlaanderen.be/en/gift-tax has a load of information.

(or other equivalent sites if you are not in the Flanders region)

Also remember to consider currency conversion costs, if you ever actually are moving money from the country to country.

This could be (and probably is) a money laundry issue. I suggest to have a clear written contract for this loan, preferably with a lawyer representing you alone.

@vicky yes, I red that article and it’s more about gifts. In my case it’s not a gift, I want to borrow money in euro and return it later without paying any interest.

@littleadv, you are correct, I also planned to sign specific document.

In what way is it not a gift? You're not paying any interest and do not have any commitments, it is a gift for all intents and purposes. Since you're not obligated to pay anything back ("zero % of interest and I am free to give the money back whenever I want") I find it hard to argue that it is anything but a gift.

@Vicky thank you for the reference, it explains the issue. In Flanders, it is the recipient that pays the gift tax, which is why the OP is trying to disguise a gift as a loan.

@littleadv Agree with you and this is what was my doubt. I was following my logic, but for the authorities of course it will look as a gift and won’t be able to avoid 30% taxes
